# Error while saving a textAlignment in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save the textAlignment(TextView) in firebase
But I am facing this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:withCompletionBlock:) Cannot store object of type __SwiftValue at algmint. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
> (lldb)

What is the correct way?

This is the func

```
var data0 : NSTextAlignment?
func SetText () {

    var textt = detilesTextview.textAlignment
    textt = .left
    data0 = textt
}
```

This is about sending it to Firebase

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let sub = ref.child("Sub")
                    let udid = sub.childByAutoId().key
                    let setRef = sub.child(udid!)
                    let value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "ImgSub" : imgSub , "SubID" : udid , "Color" : self.labelColor , "algmint" : self.data0 ] as [String : Any]
                    setRef.setValue(value) { error, ref in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "تم بنجاح", message: "تم ارسال الرساله", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "حسنا", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

                                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
```

This is model file

```
import FirebaseAuth

class QRModel {
var ImgSub : String?
var detiles : String?
var sub : String?
var SubID : String?
var id : String?
var Color : String?
var algmint : Data?
}

extension QRModel {
    static func Qmodel ( dic : [String : Any] , key : String)-> QRModel {
      


    let Qmod = QRModel()
    Qmod.id = key
    Qmod.ImgSub = dic["ImgSub"] as? String
    Qmod.detiles = dic["detiles"] as? String
    Qmod.sub = dic["sub"] as? String
    Qmod.SubID = dic["SubID"] as? String
    Qmod.Color = dic["Color"] as? String
    Qmod.algmint = dic["algmint"] as? Data
    return Qmod
}
}
```

Comment: Firebase for iOS only slows you to save numbers, strings, dictionaries, or arrays. For alignment you could save a String that represents the value, ie, "left". And then, when you download the object from the database, you create the instance with a switch or something alike.

Comment: ‏I don't want you to be stuck in one direction
‏There is more than one message
‏Each message can come in a different direction
‏like blogging
‏There is a way, but I don't understand it, I hope someone can help us

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 That is indeed the problem, and the solution. If you could post it as an answer, and add an example of how to do the conversion, that would probably be useful for more people than just OP.

Comment: Done. For @bdriii case, you just need to add the extension and then "self.data0.toString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase for iOS only alows you to save numbers, strings, dictionaries, or arrays. For `NSTextAlignment` you could save a `String` that represents the value. And then, when you download the object from the database, you create the instance with a switch. I would use `extensions` to simplify further use.

In any part of your code (outside the scope of classes), add the following:

```
extension NSTextAlignment{
    //NSTextAlignment --> NSString
    func toString()->NSString{
        switch self {
        case .center:
            return "center"
        case .justified:
            return "justified"
        case .left:
            return "left"
        case .natural:
            return "natural"
        case .right:
            return "right"
        default:
            return "natural"
        }
    }

    //NSString --> NSTextAlignment
    init(_ string:NSString){
        switch string {
        case "center":
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.center.rawValue)!
        case "justified":
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.justified.rawValue)!
        case "left":
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.left.rawValue)!
        case "natural":
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.natural.rawValue)!
        case "right":
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.right.rawValue)!
        default:
            self.init(rawValue: NSTextAlignment.natural.rawValue)!
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the following whenever you need it.

For uploading to Firebase:

```
textAlignment.toString()
```

For downloading from Firebase:

```
NSTextAlignment(downloaded_value)
```